# Alternative YouTube interface that is centered around my subscriptions and permits grouping or tagging of subscriptions?

Tags: linux, youtube

Generally speaking, unless I'm searching on YouTube, I don't want to see anything unless it's on my subscription list. Is there any interface that allows for more efficient navigation based on subscriptions?

I would ideally like to tag the subscription. I have over a hundred of them.

Basically, I have

- News,
- Computer/IT/Programming
- Mindless Entertainment
- Music

Anything that groups them together is useless. I just something like a `multireddit` for YouTube. [I see I'm not the only one requesting this either](https://www.reddit.com/r/Lightbulb/comments/810cgk/multitube_like_multireddit_for_youtube/). Is there anything like this that runs on Linux? Or, functions in a browser interface?

Answer (score 1):

Some solutions may be,

- [Subscribe to YouTube channels via RSS](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/111680/how-to-find-channel-rss-feed-on-youtube) and use your RSS feed reader to handle grouping, tagging etc.
- Use [PocketTube](https://yousub.info/) (available for [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/youtube-subscription-groups/), [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pockettube-youtube-subscr/kdmnjgijlmjgmimahnillepgcgeemffb), [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.youtubesubscriptionmanager) and [iOS](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/pockettube-for-youtube/id1475688814)). It does not seem to be free software although the Firefox version claims it is released under the Mozilla Public License 2.0.
- Create a Google account for every category of interest and use [Firefox Multi-Account Containers](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/multi-account-containers/) to use these accounts simultaneously.  Then visit YouTube via the [subscription feed](https://www.youtube.com/feed/subscriptions) instead of the homepage or use the bell icon to only see your subscriptions.
- [FreeTube](https://freetubeapp.io/) (“The Private YouTube Client”) will have [profiles](https://freetube.writeas.com/behind-the-scenes-local-profiles-preview) that let you quickly switch between lists of subscriptions in version 0.7.0.

**Extra**: In github, see this [feature request](https://github.com/omarroth/invidious/issues/482) for [invidio.us](https://invidio.us) and this [pull request](https://github.com/TeamNewPipe/NewPipe/pull/2309) for NewPipe.